# How to access Zoom recordings with password using oauth via api?

Tags: oauth, zoom-sdk

We have an app which is not in public marketplace of Zoom right now but we use it to import Zoom meeting recordings of our clients on our platform. Normal getting of videos from Zoom api is working fine, but when we try to import videos which have a password on them, we are able to get to the `download_url` by hitting the `<meetings/{meetingId}/recordings>` end point but when we hit the download url using with the authorization (outh) token, we get Forbidden response.

The documentation only says on https://marketplace.zoom.us/docs/api-reference/zoom-api/cloud-recording/recordingget to use a JWT token for downloading the recording but how do we proceed if we have an Oauth app?

Answer (score 1):

as noted by dark light, you cannot use oauth to download the files... but you can use jwt and its kinda simple....

```
#pre-reqs, PSZoom powershell module, an admin account on zoom, your oauth set and your JWT Auth set.
#update this to match your environment - you will need a JWT token, and they expire regularly, 
#you will need your from and to dates, your download location, 
#and to choose if you want auto delete (change no to yes AND uncomment the remove section on line 38
#autodelete is untested, be careful
import-module PSZoom
$Global:ZoomApiKey    = 'YOUR API KEY'  
$Global:ZoomApiSecret = 'YOUR API SECRET'
$base = "C:\working\Testing\"
$fromfile1 = "C:\working\zoomusers_$((Get-Date).ToString('MM-dd-yyyy')).csv"
$fromfile2 = "c:\working\rcdngs_$((Get-Date).ToString('MM-dd-yyyy')).csv"
$fromfile3 = "c:\working\DWNLD_$((Get-Date).ToString('MM-dd-yyyy')).csv"
$downlog = "c:\working\ZoomDownloads_$((Get-Date).ToString('MM-dd-yyyy')).log"
$deletelog = "c:\working\ZoomDelete_$((Get-Date).ToString('MM-dd-yyyy')).log"
$exportPath = 'c:\working\files\'
$Users = Import-Csv -Path $FromFile1
$MIDS = Import-Csv -Path $fromfile2
$Links = Import-Csv -Path $fromfile3
$jwt='YOUR VERY LONG JWT TOKEN'
$AToken='/?access_token='
$autodelete= 'NO'
Get-ZoomUsers -AllPages -status active | Where-Object {$_.type -eq "2"} |select id,first_name,last_name,email,pmi | export-csv $fromfile1 -NoTypeInformation
foreach ($user in $Users) {
Get-zoomRecordings -userId $user.email -From 2021-09-20 -PageSize 300 -To 2021-09-24 |select -ExpandProperty meetings| export-csv $fromfile2 -NoTypeInformation 
foreach ($MID in $MIDS) {
Get-ZoomMeetingRecordings -MeetingId $MID.uuid | select -property topic,start_time -ExpandProperty recording_files| select -property topic,start_time,meeting_id,download_url| export-csv $fromfile3 -Append -NoTypeInformation}
}
foreach ($Link in $Links) {
$MTD = $Link.start_time.substring(0,10)
$path = ($base + $Link.topic)
If(!(test-path $path))
{
      New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $path
}
$uri= ($link.download_url + $AToken + $jwt)
$inc = 1
$file=($path + "\" + $mtd + "-" + $inc + ".mp4")
If(!(test-path $file)) {
$wc=New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$wc.DownloadFile($uri,$file)  
echo "downloading $file" | out-file $downlog -append}
else {
$inc=$inc+1
$file=($path + "\" + $mtd + "-" + $inc + ".mp4")
$wc=New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$wc.DownloadFile($uri,$file)  
echo "downloading $file" | out-file $downlog -append}

if($autodelete -eq 'YES'){
    #Remove-ZoomMeetingRecordings -MeetingId $link.meeting_id -Action delete
    echo ($link.topic + " on " + $MTD + " was succesfully delted on $((Get-Date).ToString('MM-dd-yyyy_hh-mm-ss'))") | out-file $deletelog -append
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So I found out the issue in Zoom discussions and currently as on 22 April 2020, it is not possible. You might need to use notification feature for that as of now - https://devforum.zoom.us/t/best-way-to-download-recording-files-programmatically/7386/20